# How to find the bottleneck for slow rsync

Tags: networking, performance, rsync, io, bottleneck

I want to find the bottleneck for a slow rsync.

I see these parts (on byte flow order):

- IO on source
- CPU on source
- Network
- CPU on destination
- IO on destination

How can I debug this?

Comment: you forgot CPU in your list

Comment: Also the number of files/inodes. In my experience, if I first (programmatically) TAR a folder with many files, rsync will be much, much faster. Same with scp etc.

Comment: @JayMcTee thank you for your hint. We could use a overlay filesystem for those parts which hardly ever change: one layer the static tar, and the next layer the rare changes. I guess it should be possible to mount a tar ....

Comment: Yes the number of files/inodes does matter. In my question I don't want to change the layout of the directory tree.